# Floating operations. Is there loop-carried dependency?

Tags: optimization, x86

The following code presents QuickSort. I am trying to make it faster. Please help.

```
global sort
sort:
        push    ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    push    edi
    push    esi
    push    ebx
    sub esp, 28
    mov eax, dword [ebp+8]
    mov esi, dword [ebp+12]
    mov dword [ebp-32], 1
    lea edi, [eax-1]
    sal eax, 2
    lea edx, [eax+18]
    movss   xmm1, dword [esi-4+eax]
    mov dword [ebp-28], edi
    and edx, -16
    sub esp, edx
    lea edx, [esp+3]
    shr edx, 2
    lea ebx, [0+edx*4]
    mov dword [4+edx*4], edi
    mov dword [0+edx*4], 0
    xor edi, edi
    mov dword [ebp-36], ebx
.L14:
    mov eax, dword [ebp-28]
    lea edx, [edi-1]
    cmp eax, edi
    lea ebx, [esi+eax*4]
    jle .L15
    lea eax, [esi+edi*4]
.L18:
    movss   xmm0, dword [eax]
    comiss  xmm1, xmm0
    jb  .L16
    add edx, 1
    lea ecx, [esi+edx*4]
    movss   xmm2, dword [ecx]
    movss   dword [ecx], xmm0
    movss   dword [eax], xmm2
.L16:
    add eax, 4
    cmp eax, ebx
    jne .L18
    movss   xmm1, dword [ebx]
.L15:
    lea eax, [esi+4+edx*4]
    cmp edx, edi
    movss   xmm0, dword [eax]
    movss   dword [eax], xmm1
    movss   dword [ebx], xmm0
    jg  .L19
    sub dword [ebp-32], 2
    lea edi, [edx+2]
    cmp edi, dword [ebp-28]
    jl  .L25
.L21:
    mov eax, dword [ebp-32]
    test    eax, eax
    js  .L11
    mov edi, dword [ebp-36]
    lea eax, [edi+eax*4]
    mov edi, dword [eax]
    mov ecx, edi
    mov dword [ebp-28], edi
    mov edi, dword [eax-4]
    movss   xmm1, dword [esi+ecx*4]
    jmp .L14
.L19:
    mov edi, dword [ebp-32]
    mov eax, dword [ebp-36]
    mov dword [eax+edi*4], edx
    lea edi, [edx+2]
    cmp edi, dword [ebp-28]
    jge .L21
.L25:
    mov ebx, dword [ebp-32]
    mov ecx, dword [ebp-36]
    movaps  xmm1, xmm0
    lea eax, [ecx+ebx*4]
    mov ecx, dword [ebp-28]
    mov dword [eax+4], edi
    mov dword [eax+8], ecx
    mov eax, ebx
    add eax, 2
    mov dword [ebp-32], eax
    jns .L14
.L11:
    lea esp, [ebp-12]
    pop ebx
    pop esi
    pop edi
    pop ebp
    ret
```

Comment: Kind of hard to read this when you show jumps as byte offsets instead of target labels. And when you don't say what it's supposed to do. If this can be rewritten to take advantage of SIMD with SSE instructions then it will probably be a lot faster.

Comment: SSE would be faster and AVX would even be faster, and the result will be more consistent

Comment: Yeah, doesn't look like any loop-carried dependencies other than the loop counters.  What does this do, and why do you care?  It looks like a swap if >= or something, or maybe part of an insertion-sort?  But what's in `st1` before the first iteration?

Comment: Is this code you wrote by hand?  If so, why?  Why not use SSE for more efficient FP comparisons (`fcomi` is 3 uops, `ucomiss` is 2 uops and works with a memory operand).  Also for `minss` / `maxss` instructions.  Not to mention the packed version of those, to build a sorting network out of `minps` / `maxss` comparators.  (Google that).

Comment: Actually with those label names and lack of comments, this is compiler output, right?  With the default `-mfpmath=387` for `-m32`.

Comment: Ok, I edited my first post.